# Is there a noun for the verb thrive/flourish/prosper/burgeon?

Tags: nouns

Consider the following sentence:
"The government strongly profited from the company's ..."

I could use the term "well-being" here, but it doesn't quite seem to capture the same meaning as a noun of the verbs thrive/flourish/prosper/burgeon (or a similar word) would. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A noun for *thrive* is *thrift*. A noun for *flourish* is *flourish*. A noun (obsolete) for *burgeon* is *burgeon*. A noun for *prosper* is *prosperity*. I expect none of these has the meaning you want, although *prosperity* comes close.

Comment: Thriving, flourishing, prospering, or burgeoning seem fine.

Comment: "... strong performance."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

success, productivity, prosperity, even fecundity (though that's a bit biological)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:
• *expansion*, “The act or process of *[expanding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expand#Verb)*” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expansion#Noun) (ie an “increase in extent, number, volume or scope”)
• *proliferation*, “The act of increasing or rising; augmentation, amplification, enlargement, escalation, aggrandizement” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proliferation#Noun)
• *aggrandizement*, “The act of aggrandizing, or the state of being aggrandized or exalted in power, rank, honor, or wealth; exaltation; enlargement” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggrandizement#Noun) (*[Aggrandize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggrandize#Verb)* means (among related senses) “To make great; to enlarge; to increase”.)

Use of phrases like *high-flying growth*, *expansive growth*, *explosive development*, etc seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

**"growth rate"**

"The government strongly profited from the company's high growth rate."  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate)

Answer (score 0):

It may be flexing the rules on language somewhat, and it's likely to sound strange in many contexts, but depending on what you're looking for, you may get away with using the gerund form of the verbs.

Example: In a list... The result of human nature's pursuit:
Proliferation,
Thriving,
Flourishing,
Fecundity,
etc.

It is also the typical construction in specific language constructs.

Example: Dearest Friend, I hope you don't mind my relative flourishing in the face of your recent setbacks.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps "vigor" is the word you want.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).